# Unloading data from Snowflake to txt format file

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to extract data from Snowflake and external S3 stage the data in txt file format that can be sent over to vendor using SFTP. But I am facing SQL compilation error -

File format script:

```
create or replace file format my_format
  type = txt
  field_delimiter = '|'
  skip_header = 0
  null_if = ('NULL', 'null')
  empty_field_as_null = true
```

Please advise how can we unload data to txt format in S3 external stage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change the txt to csv and the file_extension to txt:

```
create or replace file format my_format
  type = csv
  field_delimiter = '|'
  skip_header = 0
  null_if = ('NULL', 'null')
  empty_field_as_null = true
  file_extension = 'txt'
```

Although it shows CSV, it's actually text with delimited fields and your pipe (vertical bar) overrides use of the comma as a column delimiter.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried keeping type as csv, but was seeing csv.gz instead of txt.gz. Is there any way that file name can be renamed to filename.txt.gz instead of filename.csv.gz? Eventually, we would want to unzip the file and send the txt format file to our vendor

Comment: I updated the answer. You can set the file_extension = 'txt'